# Tell 'nice' to stop +19 processes if load >= 1

Tags: nice

I've noticed my computer gets sluggish when the load increases past 1 
(ie, the first number after "load average:" from the "uptime" command).

Heavy-duty processes (like rsync) often raise the load above 1, even 
if I renice them lowest priority (+19). Renicing them helps a little, 
but not a lot.

Can I tell nice (or another program) to completely stop (kill -STOP) 
any +19 processes when the load increases over 1 (and resume when the 
load decreases to .75 or something)?

Comment: load average doesn't mean particularly much... it's just the number of processes actively running in specific time intervals. A load of 1.0 doesn't mean the system's fully busy, just that there's at least 1 process running at all times. It could be 20 processes each running for 5% of the time.

Comment: Oh, I know. I've seen load average go to 120 once (the system was completely unresponsive). Someone once told me this number indicated percentage of CPU used (with 120% possible because Unix fudges this the same way they fudge in "df"), but I now think that's not true. I've just personally noticed that my system gets sluggish when the load average goes to 1.50, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FreeBSD has IDLE process class - see rtprio(1) manual page - so you can assign IDLE priority to rsync so it won't get timeslices when there are normal processes active.

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rtprio&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html

Linux has ionice(1) for CFQ io scheduler:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice
Very similar concept, but for I/O.